Banach lattice hull of a Banach space
I am interested in defining some Banach lattice properties for subsets of arbitrary Banach spaces. So it would be useful to have the notion of Banach lattice hull $E(X)$ of a Banach space $X$.
I expect $X$ to be a closed subspace of $E(X)$.
Every $X$ can be embedded in $C(B_{X^*})$, where $B_{X^*}$ is compact with the weak$^*$ topology, but I would need the isomorphic properties of $E(X)$ to be similar to those of $X$. For example, it need to have $E(X)=X$, or at least $X$ a closed sublattice of $E(X)$, when X is a Banach lattice.
Is it possible to find in the literature something like the described notion?

I don't know if this might be useful/relevant & I believe you already knew the free Banach lattice generated by a given Banach space https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2018.03.001

This recent article may also be relevant https://doi.org/10.1007/s43037-024-00346-w
